# method chaining, returning an object from a list and getting values from it

Tags: java, oop, boolean, method-chaining

what I have is a list of Dog objects, in the objects there contains a value that is a Boolean to show whether the dog as completed a training or not. What im trying to do is iterate over the list and only return Dog() objects that have completed training, for instance if their are 12 dogs, and only 3 have completed training, the loop should only print those objects.

```
else if (input == 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
            //Create a temporary value to hold the object.
            Object tempHold = dogKennel.getAnimal(i);
            //If animal has not graduated, skip, else print.
            if (!(tempHold.getGraduation())) {
              continue;
            }
            else {
                  System.out.println(dogKennel);
        }
}
```

getAnimal(i) returns the object at int i

the method .getGraduation is defined and does return a Boolean however the compiler doesnt want to recognize temp value as is, and doesnt go beyond that value. the compiler keeps suggesting to cast tempHold, but even if I do, it doesnt work.

i feel like it would work if i could get it to compile, as the object that is returned would have a getGraduation() method (it is defined for the super class of the animal.)

Comment: If `dogKennel` only contains `Dog`s, why would you retrieve them as `Object`s. Why not `Dog tempHold = dogKennel.getAnimal(i)`.

Comment: Make it `Animal tempHold = dogKennel.getAnimal(i)`

Comment: @jrook, there are two kennel objects in the program, one of them is a dog kennel

Comment: @AustinHoward, in that case, you can do an extra check : `if (tempHold instanceof Dog) tempHold.getGraduation();` A more optimal way in my opinion would be to make `Graduation` an interface and have all Animal classes implement it.

Comment: @AustinHoward, see my answer please which I believe is the right approach to the problem you have described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however the compiler doesn't want to recognize temp value as is, ...the compiler keeps suggesting to cast tempHold, but even if I do, it doesn't work.

The compiler is telling you two things:

1. An `Object` is NOT a `Dog` (the opposite is true. A `Dog` is an `Object`).
2. class `Object` does not have method `isGraduated()` defined for them.

To fix this, you can cast `Object` to `Dog`:

```
Dog tempHold = (Dog)dogKennel.getAnimal(i);
```

Now that we have a `Dog`, we can safely invoke `isGraduated()` on it. But the problem is we canNOT be sure that we have a `Dog`. We may as well have a `Cat` if we get the `Animal` from another kennel. In that case, you will get a `ClassCastException` which tells you that `Cat`s cannot be cast as `Dog`s.

To avoid getting run time exceptions, you can add a check:

```
Object tempHold = dogKennel.getAnimal(i);
if(tempHold instanceof Dog) {
    Dog dog = (Dog)tempHold;
    System.out.println(dog.isGraduated());
}
```

The `instanceof` check fixes the problem.

There are ways to avoid this run time check altogether. One would be to create an interface:

```
public interface CanGraduate {
    default boolean isGraduated() {
        return false;
    };
}
```

Then make all `Animal`s implement this interface:

```
public abstract class Animal implements CanGraduate {
//Behavior common among all animals
}
```

You can now freely add new animal types and be assured that you can safely invoke `isGraduated()` on them and get a `false` value as long as they inherit from the above `Animal` class.

For dogs, `isGraduated()` is supposed to be more meaningful. So you can override it in their case:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    private boolean _graduated = true;

    @Override
    public boolean isGraduated() {
        return _graduated; //or some complex logic that determines graduation
    }
}
```

With this structure, you no longer need to worry about invoking the method on any kind of `Animal`.

As an example, let us see some driver code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog1 = new Dog();
        Dog dog2 = new Dog();
        Cat cat1 = new Cat();
        Cat cat2 = new Cat();

        List<Animal> dogKennel = List.of(dog1, dog2);
        List<Animal> catKennel = List.of(cat1, cat2);

        for(Animal x : catKennel) {
            System.out.println(x.isGraduated());
        }
    }
}
```

The program will simply output `false` since `Cat`s can never graduate. If the kennel contained `Dog`s, it would output the actual graduation status of the dog.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter the list for just ones with a certain condition, the most common way to do that these days is with the [`Stream::filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) method.

It would look like this:

```
List<Dog> completedTraining = 
    dogKennel
    .stream()
    .filter(
        dog -> !dog.getGraduation()
    )
    .collect(
        Collectors.toList()
    )
;
```

Comment: this is a bit beyond my knowledge at the moment, so im a little lost to what the code is doing. but it looks like its creating a new list of dogs that have graduated correct?

Comment: Yes, basically the code above filters for all dogs that completed the task and put them on another dog list

Comment: @AustinHoward correct. It’ll have the objects where the filter condition returns true for.

Comment: @AustinHoward Yes. If `dogKennel` is a collection such as `List` or `Set`, then calling `stream` produces a `Stream` object which can provide each contained `Dog` object one after another. Calling `Stream::filter` applies a `Predicate` (a test resulting in a bollean value, a true or false) against each `Dog` object in the stream. Those dogs flunking the test are ignored while those passing are passed to the next call. That next call `collect` places the dogs who passed the test into a new `List`.

Comment: @AustinHoward, @cbender, according to the criteria set by OP, this answer is wrong. if you are not sure `dogKennel` only contains `Dog`s, then this will throw a `ClassCastException`. If you are sure, then in your own code, simply change `Object` to `Dog`.

Comment: @jrook yes this kennel contains specific dogs, but now i know two ways to complete the program in general, i guess it should've been more obvious to me that i needed a cast to the class and not an object. but thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @AustinHoward, casting can cause a `ClassCastException` if the object does not hold the class that implements `isGraduated()` method. It is not safe.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others have said, the `getGraduation()` method is only defined presumably in the Dog class. This means that the method can only be called on Objects with the type `Dog`. To define a variable with type `Dog` you can do `Dog temphold = *whatever*`. The reason it wants you to cast is because Object is a supertype of Dog. If you'd like to read more about casting you can here: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/what-is-type-casting-in-java-class-interface-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Basically, all you have to do is a cast to convert the object

```
if (!(((Dog)tempHold).getGraduation())) 
{
    continue;
}
```

this casting tells the compiler that even though `tempHold` is an object of the `Object` class it also is an object of the `Dog` class and should have all of its properties